# Is the home team allowed to set the boundary as they wish?

Tags: rules, cricket

Is the home team responsible for the setting of the boundary? Can they set the boundary in such a way that may benefit them? E.g., supposing they tend to hit the ball straight (or to cow corner), can they shorten the straight (cow corner) boundaries and lengthen the other boundaries? (And, if the boundary needs to be in a certain shape, can they shorten/lengthen it at will?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cricket ground specifications](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/cricket-ground-specifications)

Comment: +1, I dont think it is a duplicate. It is just a related question. Couldn't see the questions "Is the home team responsible for the setting of the boundary? Can they set the boundary in such a way that may benefit them?" in the above link.

Comment: @Bogdanovist I did not stipulate _international_ cricket.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **NO.** Home team is not supposed to set the boundary as they wish. Some rules are applied for boundary setting as well. Even though the home team is responsible for setting up the ground.

As per ICC Standard Playing Conditions, the minimum and maximum size of the playing surface. Law 19.1 of ICC Test Match Playing Conditions states:

> "The playing area shall be a minimum of 150 yards (137.16 metres) from
>   boundary to boundary square of the pitch, with the shorter of the two
>   square boundaries being a minimum 65 yards (59.43 metres). The
>   straight boundary at both ends of the pitch shall be a minimum of 70
>   yards (64.00 metres). Distances shall be measured from the centre of
>   the pitch to be used. In all cases the aim shall be to provide the
>   largest playing area, subject to no boundary exceeding 90 yards (82.29
>   meters) from the centre of the pitch to be used. "

They can set the boundary as long as they follow the above rule. But the above rule doesn't give the freedom to reduce the boundary a lot. It should be a minimum of 65 yards and max of 90 yards. So the chances of setting a boundary as mentioned in question is very less.

Comment: Thanks. However, supposing we are not talking specifically about _international_ cricket (and I wasn't), but cricket in general, is the short answer then "Yes, unless countered by relevant playing conditions"? Meaning that, in general, the home team has _at least some_ freedom in laying the boundary.

Comment: I still dont think any cricketing authority would allow for home team to set the ground as per their wish unless it is a street cricket. Every cricketing authority will have certain rules, be in international or domestic matches.

Comment: I've looked up my national authority's "accommodation regulations", and it only _recommends_ to make the field of play as large as possible. (However, they do stipulate that it is allowed to "round off" corners.) I guess that leaves some room for "manipulation", but less than I initially suspected.