# What is the standard measurements of a cricket ground?

Tags: cricket

What is the standard measurements such as straight distance , on-off distance, radius of the ground etc of a cricket ground ?

Comment: Welcome to Sports.SE. This question is a possible duplicate of http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2298/753